# SphinxQL connection issue (while daemon is listening)

Tags: mysql, sphinxql

I'm trying to get my SphinxQL-installation to work on my Ubuntu 16.04LTS environment. However, I can't connect to the server. The configuration I use is below:

```
searchd
{
  listen            = 9306:mysql41
  log               = /var/log/sphinxsearch/searchd.log
  query_log         = /var/log/sphinxsearch/query.log
  read_timeout      = 5
  max_children      = 30
  pid_file          = /var/run/sphinxsearch/searchd.pid
  seamless_rotate   = 1
  preopen_indexes   = 1
  unlink_old        = 1
  binlog_path       = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data
}
```

In order to confirm or the daemon is running, I executed: `sudo systemctl status sphinxsearch.service` which returns:

```
sphinxsearch.service - LSB: Fast standalone full-text SQL search engine
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/sphinxsearch; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-06-07 11:23:09 CEST; 12min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 10552 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/sphinxsearch stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 10614 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/sphinxsearch start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/sphinxsearch.service
           ├─10621 /usr/bin/searchd
           └─10622 /usr/bin/searchd

Jun 07 11:23:09 Serv001 sphinxsearch[10614]: listening on all interfaces, port=9306
Jun 07 11:23:09 Serv001 sphinxsearch[10614]: Sphinx 2.2.9-id64-release (rel22-r5006)
Jun 07 11:23:09 Serv001 sphinxsearch[10614]: Copyright (c) 2001-2015, Andrew Aksyonoff
Jun 07 11:23:09 Serv001 sphinxsearch[10614]: Copyright (c) 2008-2015, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)
Jun 07 11:23:09 Serv001 sphinxsearch[10614]: precaching index 'I2455'
Jun 07 11:23:09 Serv001 sphinxsearch[10614]: [1.4K blob data]
Jun 07 11:23:09 Serv001 sphinxsearch[10614]: Copyright (c) 2001-2015, Andrew Aksyonoff
Jun 07 11:23:09 Serv001 sphinxsearch[10614]: Copyright (c) 2008-2015, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)
Jun 07 11:23:09 Serv001 sphinxsearch[10614]: sphinxsearch.
Jun 07 11:23:09 Serv001 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Fast standalone full-text SQL search engine.
```

To verify that the daemon is listening, I executed: `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN` which shows me:

```
searchd   10622 sphinxsearch    8u  IPv4 423245474      0t0  TCP *:9306 (LISTEN)
```

However, when I try to connect with: `mysql -h0 -P9306` it returns me: `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '0' (115)` **after a while**

*Note: The indexes have built without a problem, so a DB-connection has been established earlier*

*Note2: I followed this [documentation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-sphinx-on-ubuntu-16-04)*

**So, what am I doing wrong that I can't connect to SphinxQL at port 9306?**

**EDIT:**
Output of `iptables -L`:
[image: Output]

Comment: Anything interesting in "iptables -L" ?

Comment: I have added the output in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your iptables it looks like you blacklist everything (see the DROP line in the INPUT chain) and then whitelist only selected ports. So to allow access to 9306 you should do

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 9306 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Wauw this was quite obvious... Thanks for your reply!